# One-way Trapdoor Function

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

Do the functions of the collatz conjecture and their inverses model a Trapdoor Function?

If given a, b, a^-1, b^-1 and your choice of f(x), is it “hard in the average case” to find some secret x?

I propose that the probability: 
Pr[f(F(f(x)))=f(x)] < n^-c
=Pr[(2^-n)^2] < (n^-(n-1))
Simplifies to:
1 < (log(2)) * ((log(n))^-1) * (e^(n+1))

Looking at the picture from Wikipedia that others are referencing.
Let D be the domain of all natural numbers that I can choose x from.
Let R be the domain of all natural numbers that you can choose f(x) from.
The arrow marked “easy” is the promise that I am choosing a natural number that can be calculated by applying functions A and B to 1.(c(x) exists)
It is hard on average for you to calculate how to apply given functions A,B A^-1 and B^-1 to f(x) to return x.(Sometimes this time is less than the verification process)
However, I can quickly apply A^-1 and B^-1 to x until 1 is returned, retain and reverse the order the operations applied and pass you this information (t) making finding x trivial by finding the shortest path to collision.

Comment: Given integer $n\ge2$ and $i\ge0$, let $c_i=1$ if $f^{i+1}(n)=f^{i}(n)/2$ and $c_i=0$ otherwise. Let $k$ be the smallest integer such that $f^k(n)=1$. Define $c(n)=c_k2^{k} + c_{k-1}2^{k-1} + \cdots + c_02^0=(c_{k-1}\cdots c_0)_2$ where the subscript "${}_2$" means binary representation. Is it correct that you are asking whether $c(n)$ could be a trapdoor function?

Comment: What is given? If $n$ is given, then of course we know $n$. If $c(n)$ is given, whose binary representation tells us the operations that have been performed in order, then we can reverse the operations to find $n$. I could not find anything that is hard here.

Comment: Understood. My claim is that it is easy to get from n to one using the collatz conjecture steps but that it is hard to find n given the inverse of the steps and a random input. Easy to verify, hard to solve?

Comment: Given the inverse of the steps $(11111101)_2$, we can start with $1$ and perform $g_1, g_1,$$\,g_1, g_1,$$\,g_1, g_1,$$\,g_1, g_0, g_1$ in order to get the "$n$". Here $g_1(x)=2x$ and $g_0(x)=(x-1)/3$. It is **very easy to solve**. There is no need of a random input.

Comment: Excellent clarification. Now what I am trying to change my question to is “Given G1(x) and G0(x) and n return c(n)”

Comment: Well, it is better to raise a new question. It is not a good idea to change the question to invalidate the existing answers (and comments).

Comment: In my welcome to stack exchange email it mentions following the post and making edits to clarify.

Comment: You missed a basic requirement of a trapdoor function, a requirement that has nothing to do trapdoor. If you give me the number 1 (a.k.a $f(x)$), I should be able to know **independent of you** whether my guess $x'$ could be $x$ or not. In your setup, I have no way to know whether my guess $x'$ is $x$ or not except by asking you to tell me.

Comment: Apparently, either you or I missed something very basic about arithmetic, functions, one-way functions or trapdoor functions. I cannot understand why you were talking about deterministic machines and where I was trying to use "nondeterministic power". It occurs to me that you might be misled by [the illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOajr.jpg) you referred to.

Comment: I am reducing the complexity. If you will allow nondeterministic rules then I would invoke factorial based tree splitting. Does that bolster my case?

Comment: Here is another way I have been trying to explain my case: you are given two functions a and b and are told that starting at 1 you can apply a or b any number of times in any order and return some n. How long does it take to find the solution?

Comment: Now if I give you the functions a^-1 and b^-1 and the order I apply them in to get to 1 then you can reverse the order of the application and use  functions a and b as fast. This is how I understand a Trapdoor function to work.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct, except that you have to make sure that I cannot compute function $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ efficiently. Otherwise, even if you do not tell me how to compute $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ easily, I may find out by myself. For example, if you aske me to use $g_0$ and $g_1$ to move 1 to $n$, I will use $f_0$ and $f_1$ to move $n$ to 1 first. Then I will tell you how to use $g_0$ and $g_1$ to move 1 to $n$.

Comment: Now to explain how I think this is useful, an example. I give you a, b, a^-1, b^-1 is it “hard in the average case” to find the secret n as defined by the one-way function wiki page? You don’t know the length which makes it hard, no?

Comment: Have we reached the point where we consider ?https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39878/how-to-show-that-a-one-way-function-proves-that-p-≠-np/39884

Comment: It seems to me that the later edits have invalidated [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/112027/)  by removing the definition of $f$. While you indeed should improve your question with edits to clarify your problem, I think that now your question text is too distant from the original and that it is better to ask a new question at this point. However, do try to take into account the advice and answers given here, because otherwise you are likely to only have that repeated on your new question.

Comment: Discrete lizard - This answer does not address the original unedited question “Do the functions of the collatz conjecture and their inverses model a Trapdoor Function?” It’s the thesis of my paper and I have not changed it since sharing my findings.

Answer (score 5):

In order to break a one-way function, it suffices to be able to find a single preimage. Given $x$, $f(2x) = x$, so finding a preimage of an *arbitrary* input is easy. Hence it's not a one-way function at all.

Comment: A value $x$ is a preimage of a value $y$ with respect to a function $f$ if $f(x) = y$. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Under your strange definition, the function $f(x) = \lfloor x/2 \rfloor$ would also work.

Comment: The problem seems to be a basic confusion about what one-way functions are. I suggest reading a textbook.

Comment: @LanceWeingartz I think most people here do not want to watch a video to try to understand you. So, asking people not to help you unless they watch the video, means they will likely not help you. It will be much easier to understand you if you can summarize the point of the video here and how it relates to the question. In that way, we can properly respond to what you're asking and more easily ask for clarification.

Comment: @LanceWeingartz You don't make any sense. Oneway functions only make sense if there is _one_ pre-image. Possibly if there are multiple pre-images, and they are all hard to find. For the Collatz function, _every_ pre-image is absolutely trivial to find. Of course whether I got the number 16 by calculating f(5) = 16 or f(32) = 16 is impossible to do using mathematics, but that's completely missing the point.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The Wikipedia article for "one-way function" seems fine to me, so no need for a textbook. And it prominently mentions _exactly_ OPs problem: Not being one-to-one doesn't make a function a one-way function at all. If we can find _one_ pre-image quickly then it is not a one-way function.

Comment: I suggest looking at the definition of one-way function. It isn’t “easy to verify, hard to solve”. It’s a particular mathematical formulation of this idea.

Comment: I repeat my suggestion to look at the actual mathematical definition and try to understand it.

Comment: It may also help to clarify, whether you mean strong/weak one way functions in your re-formulation.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus please explain how your answer “breaks” the procedure I have presented?

Comment: It finds a preimage for your proposed one-way function.

Comment: You are not given x.

Comment: Is it hard to find f^-1(42)?

Comment: If the map of 42 -> 42 is {0100000011111101} where we switch the operations at the eighth bit. Would the bit number and function reversal be the trapdoor?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were intuiting too fast.

---

Let $f_0(x)=3x+1$ and $f_1(x)=x/2$. Their inverse functions are $g_0(x)=(x-1)/3$ and $g_1(x)=2x$, respectively. The operations in Collatz conjecture is to perform $f$ repeatedly or, in other words, perform $f_1$ as long as we have an even number and $f_0$ otherwise.

Given integer $n\ge2$ and $i\ge0$, suppose $f^{k+1}(n)=1$ where $k$ is the smallest such integer. Suppose $f^{i+1}(n)=g_{c_i}(f^{i}(n))$ for all $i$, i.e., $c_i=1$ if $f^{i+1}(n)=f^{i}(n)/2$ and $c_i=0$ if $f^{i+1}(n)=3f^{i}(n)+1$. Define function $$c:\Bbb N_{\ge2}\to\Bbb N,\ c(n)=(c_kc_{k-1}\cdots c_0)_2$$

For example, since $42\stackrel{f_1}{\to}21\stackrel{f_0}{\to}64\stackrel{f_1}{\to}32\stackrel{f_1}{\to}16\stackrel{f_1}{\to}8\stackrel{f_1}{\to}4\stackrel{f_1}{\to}2\stackrel{f_1}{\to}1$, we have $c_0=1, c_1=0, c_2=1, c_3=1, c_4=1, c_5=1, c_6=1, c_7=1$ and $c(42)=(11111101)_2$.

You are asking whether $c$ might be a good candidate for a trap-door function.

---

However, it is easy to compute $n$ given $c(n)$. All we need to do is to perform the inverse operations to the operations encoded in the binary representation of $c(n)$.

For example, given $(11111101)_2$, we simply perform $1\stackrel{g_1}{\to}2\stackrel{g_1}{\to}4$$\stackrel{g_1}{\to}8\stackrel{g_1}{\to}16$$\stackrel{g_1}{\to}32\stackrel{g_1}{\to}64$$\stackrel{g_0}{\to}21\stackrel{g_1}{\to}42$ to recover $42$.

Comment: @LanceWeingartz Then what is the input? There must be some input. If the value $c(n)$ is given, then we can compute its binary representation easily.

Comment: I got it! The map of 42 -> 42 is {0100000011111101} where we switch the operations at the eighth bit. Is the bit number the trapdoor?

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't a one-to-one function. For many y, there are two different x such that f(x) = y:

If y modulo 6 = 4, then x = (y - 1) / 3 is an odd number, and f((y-1) / 3) = y.

For all y, x = 2y is an even number, and f (2x) = y.

As you see, whatever y is, the set of values x with f(x) = y is very easy to calculate. And by the definition of a one-way function, this means f(x) is *not* a one-way function. For a one-way function, finding *any* x with f(x) = y must be hard.

It is also not a "one-way trapdoor function", which would be a function where any x with f(x) = y is hard to calculate *unless you know some secret*. No secret needs to be known to find any x, given y.

Comment: You are not given any values. You have four functions and you can choose your initial value. There exists a way to apply the four given functions to map f(x)->x. How long does it take to find this shortest path? Now consider I already know x, I can find a point where we can collide if we both have the values c(x) and c(y) and we both apply the four given functions. This act of colliding is the Trapdoor. I have been suggesting the collision take place at 1, but it does not need to.

Comment: What you say has nothing whatsoever to do with "one-way trapdoor function". Do yourself a favour and read at the very least the wikipedia article.

Comment: If {fk : Dk -> Rk} maps 42 -> 253 (for example) I cannot get over the thought that inverting 253 -> 42 is near impossible without some trapdoor. The other four bulleted criteria appear to be met.

Comment: If the map of 42 -> 42 is {0100000011111101} where we switch the operations at the eighth bit. Would the bit number and function reversal be the trapdoor?